# substract an element of an array after multiply two elements on the same array

Tags: javascript

I'm getting info from an api, and i multiply two elements from the response, and then, sum the result. This is my code so far:

```
function forTest(){
            $http.get('/api/DaApi?di=' + '2018-11-01' + '&df=' + '2018-11-01')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.result = data.data.Response;

                $scope.multiplyResult = $scope.result.map(x => x.Cost * x.Quantity).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        }
```

Everything works perfect, but now i have to make another operation before the total sum. Let's say now i have 3 elements: `Cost, Quantity and Discount`:

```
[{Quantity: 2, Cost: 1000, Discount: -100},
{Quantity: 3, Cost: 2000, Discount: -500},
{Quantity: 2, Costo: 3130, Discount: -120}]
```

And now i need to multiply Quantity per Cost, and substract the Discount(which is already a negative number). After multiply and substract, i have to sum all the results. How can i make the substraction? Inside of `map` i have to make the subsraction? Something like:

```
$scope.multiplyResult = $scope.result.map(x => (x.Cost * x.Quantity) + x.Discount)).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Or must be inside of the reduce?

Someone can help me please, i'm a little far to understand the use of map and reduce. I'm using javascript and AngularJs.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Should work fine in the map() as shown. Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: Did you run the code? What errors or issues did you encounter? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Angular other than how you're getting the data. Note that `x.Discount` is possibly a string, so you'll want `(...) + +x.Discount` to coerce it to number first, otherwise you'll get concatenation.

Comment: Maybe you want `Quantity * (Cost + Discount)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a typo.

```js
let arr = [{Quantity: 2, Cost: 1000, Discount: -100},
{Quantity: 3, Cost: 2000, Discount: -500},
{Quantity: 2, Cost: 3130, Discount: -120}];

let sum = arr.map(x => (x.Cost * x.Quantity) + x.Discount).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate and sum in a single loop by taking a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the needed properties and then add to sum the price.

```
$scope.multiplyResult = $scope.result
    .reduce((sum, { Cost, Quantity, Discount }) => sum + Cost * Quantity + Discount, 0);
```